# Perl type regex working in regex101.com, but not in command-line

Tags: regex, perl

I have a problem with matching text using Perl type regex in command-line, whereas the same regex works as expected in regex101.com. For example, I have a file test.txt with 5 lines that was created with gedit in Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and saved with Linux/Unix line endings. The lines in the file are as follows:

```
One  
Two   
Apple  
Car  
Plane
```

When I perform pattern matching in regex101.com using '\n' as a search pattern, regex101.com finds 4 matches (ie. 4 lines that contain the matching pattern, which are the first four lines). However, when I perform the same query using command line perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if /\n/' test.txt
```

the command outputs all 5 lines as if they contain a match, which, in my opinion should not be happening since the last (5th) line does not contain a newline character.

Moreover, if I search for '\nA', regex101.com correctly labels the newline character in the second line, that is followed by A in the third line.

The following command outputs nothing, as if it did not match what is obviously present in the text and identified by regex101.com

```
perl -ne 'print if /\nA/' test.txt
```

Finally, if I search for something non-sensical, such as

```
perl -ne 'print if /\n$$$$/' test.txt
```

The output is all five lines of the file test.txt, which obviously is not correct. Can someone shine a light on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: When I save the file without a newline on the last line, I'm only getting the first four lines from `perl -ne 'print if /\n/'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really three parts to this question:

#### 1. Why is this matching all five lines?

```bash
perl -ne 'print if /\n/' test.txt
```

The answer is that `gedit` is adding a newline character at the end of the file for you. It does that. Try using a different editor.

SciTE and PulsarEdit are two editors which definitely do *allow* you to create files without a final new line character. (Though under most circumstances, text files ought to contain a final new line character!)

#### 2. Why is this matching zero lines?

```bash
perl -ne 'print if /\nA/' test.txt
```

Because `-n` causes Perl to process the input one line at a time. And in each line it processes, the `\n` is at the *end* of the line, never before an uppercase A.

#### 3. Why does this match all the lines?

```bash
perl -ne 'print if /\n$$$$/' test.txt
```

Because "\n" appears at the end of each line. Multiple `$` characters are allowed because it's a zero-width assertion, so doesn't consume any of the string being matched. That is, the end of the line is matched, but the pointer isn't moved forward, so the end of the line can be matched again.

Comment: Thank you for answering and lots of useful tips. Your answers prompted me to dig a little deeper, and I learned that I can disable 'ensure-trailing-newline' option for gedit using dconf-editor to achieve the desired behavior. I have also learned that I can use something like 'perl -0777 -ne 'print $1."\n" while /(\nA)/g' test.txt' to get the desired behavior for matching in the second case. Once again, thanks four your help!